# Error: cannot resolve method

Tags: android

I am the newest Android Studio 2.1.1 and I am trying to make a simple calculator. But I got this really weird problem where for some reason, there are many methods that cannot be resolved. Just to make sure that I didn't mess up any important files, I copied all of the code and pasted it into a new fresh project. But I still got the error, maybe I need to reinstall Android Studio? [what my project looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4p4N.png)

here's my messages:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
C:\Users\Home\AndroidStudioProjects\CalcuterTest\app\src\main\java\com\kingjulian\www\calcutertest\MainActivity.java
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.612 secs
Information:30 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

and my gradle console:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

C:\Users\Home\AndroidStudioProjects\CalcuterTest\app\src\main\java\com\kingjulian\www\calcutertest\MainActivity.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             ^
  symbol: method onCreate(Bundle)
C:\Users\Home\AndroidStudioProjects\CalcuterTest\app\src\main\java\com\kingjulian\www\calcutertest\MainActivity.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ^
  symbol:   method setContentView(int)
  location: class MainActivity
C:\Users\Home\AndroidStudioProjects\CalcuterTest\app\src\main\java\com\kingjulian\www\calcutertest\MainActivity.java:24: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
C:\Users\Home\AndroidStudioProjects\CalcuterTest\app\src\main\java\com\kingjulian\www\calcutertest\MainActivity.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
                       ^
  symbol:   method findViewById(int)
  location: class MainActivity
C:\Users\Home\AndroidStudioProjects\CalcuterTest\app\src\main\java\com\kingjulian\www\calcutertest\MainActivity.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
        two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
                       ^

                           ^
  symbol:   method findViewById(int)
  location: class MainActivity
C:\Users\Home\AndroidStudioProjects\CalcuterTest\app\src\main\java\com\kingjulian\www\calcutertest\MainActivity.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
                            ^
  symbol:   method findViewById(int)
  location: class MainActivity
23 errors

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.411 secs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can draw at the moment is wonder does your class `extends` `Activity` because some of those calls cannot be "resolved" and probably means they do not know they should come from `context.findViewById()` for example. Also `@Override` also has an error line on it, so it seems like it may think you don't need to create an override. Make sure you also `import` `android.app.Activity` (This looks like an activity because it is calling onCreate() not onCreateView() which is fragments.) and `android.os.Bundle` as well.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!